# RTMP Ingest Server functionality

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming

I recently started learning about live streaming concepts and was able to initiate a live stream successfully using the WebCamera. I used an RTMP Ingest server(NGINX) and Web application as a Software encoder.

However, I don't have a solid understanding of the RTMP Ingest server or it's workings. I know every live streaming application out there provide a RTMP endpoint to which you can publish your stream. My main confusion is, when I publish my content to the ingest server via RTMP, how does the ingest server keep that information. I know I can play the stream using VLC using the RTMP link but how does the ingest server serve this information. Is it that the ingest server saves only the buffer that's recently sent from the sources or does it save the whole stream somewhere?

I was not able to find any reliable resources to understand how the ingest server actually stores or relays the published video / audio information to the people who consume it (VLC).

If someone who has knowledge on this can help or point me to the right set of resources, that would be a ton of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the server in use and how it's configured, but there's no reason to actually save anything.  A small chunk of video can stay in buffer memory and sent to clients as required.

Comment: Although it's off-topic, but I want to know: how does your Web application(encoder) publish RTMP stream to NGINX? Flash is disabled now, and the only way is to use WebRTC as encoder for H5.